# xpath to select closest table to anchor tag with a name

Tags: xpath, htmlunit

I am trying to use xpath and having difficult on how to call a table element from below html code.

There will be many tables in the html. The one i am interested is the one closest to anchor tag with given name.

Below html part is just a rough idea of what html syntax i am dealing with.

```
 <body>
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 <p>
 <font><b><a name="myTable" /></b></font></p>
 <p><b></p>
 <div><p></p></div>
 <table>
  :
  :
  :
</table>
  .
  .
  ..
```

I initially was going back to "P" element by calling get parent from anchor tag and then calling next sibling couple of times i reached table. 
I know it is not clever way to do it. one more problem is there can be variable siblings. 
So all i know for sure is the table i have to look is the closest one to anchor tag with the name.

Can some one give some ideas?

I tried this:

```
 getByXPath("//a[@name=myTable]/table"); ( it wont work because it goes to anchor tag and looks for table in children of anchor tag. But it is not the case here)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//a[@name='myTable']/following::table[1]
```